# Error in connecting email with IBM Datacap

Tags: data-capture, ibm-datacap

I am trying to connect outlook email with IBM Datacap to extract email and attachments from email inbox. I am using dcjmail.CDCjmail IMAP email import actions to import image attachments from email messages. But, I am receiving connection error.

14:55:02.692 (0)    IMap login setings. Hostname: 'outlook.office365.com'  Port: '993' Site: '' Timeout: '30000'
14:55:02.692 (0)    Starting Thread: Connect
14:55:32.734 (30031)    Connect exception: 'System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
......
14:55:32.736 (16)   Error: failed to connect or login to 'outlook.office365.com' Result = False
14:56:02.749 (30000)                      result 1[1] = false

**Datacap version: 9.1.1**

The actions in the Ruleset are given below:
[image: RuleSet actions]

Error log:
[image: Error Log]

Thanks in Advance.